# Laravel 5 automatically logs out application after 5-10 requests

Tags: php, laravel, session, cookies, laravel-5

I am using laravel 5.0,

While i am trying to do some 5-10 requests, say update .. I am using Redirect after update is done.

While it redirects the application gets logged out from project.

I have changed the session.php like this

```
'lifetime' => 1800,

'expire_on_close' => false,
```

What is the problem and how can i fix this ?

Comment: I think you have to provide more details about your problem

Comment: when you logged in you checked the remember-me? check if you have cookies named remeber_{string} and laravel_Session

Comment: @AmirBar I didn't do the remember-me option so far..

Comment: @user1191749 What information is required ..

Comment: @ImtiazPabel Even i tried in incognito mode